# Web Filter cannot autowired spring bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I found in Web Filter, the autowired bean cannot be initialized, like code below

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;

public class ClientIpFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
}
```

And register Bean in Configuration

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
     @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
            FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
            ClientIpFilter securityFilter = new ClientIpFilter();
            registrationBean.setFilter(securityFilter);
            registrationBean.setOrder(1);
            return registrationBean;
        }           
}
```

Is this because Filter is inited before other bean? If yes, how can I use spring beans in web filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `@Component` annotation for ClientIpFilter class.

Comment: Yes, this works. I register filter as component, and autowired it in the CustomWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter .